# Save and load function only half works?

Tags: javascript, save

I have recently started a clicker game and I managed to program a save and load game script... The save and load function seems to save and load my clicks (cookies) but not my autoclick shop (cursors and cursorCost) I was wondering what I done wrong?

```
var cookies = 0;

function cookieClick(number){
    cookies = cookies + number;
    document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
} 

var cursors = 0;

function buyCursor(){
    var cursorCost = Math.floor(25 * Math.pow(1.5,cursors));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(cookies >= cursorCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        cursors = cursors + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
        cookies = cookies - cursorCost;                          //removes the cookies spent
        document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;  //updates the number of cookies for the user
    } else {
        alert("Unfortunately you cannot afford that!");
    }
    var nextCost = Math.floor(25 * Math.pow(1.5,cursors));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextCost;  //updates the cursor cost for the user
}

window.setInterval(function(){

    cookieClick(cursors);

}, 1000);


function reset() {
  document.getElementById("cursors").reset();
  document.getElementById("cookies").reset();
}

function save() {
localStorage.setItem('cookies', cookies);
localStorage.setItem('cursors', cursors);
localStorage.setItem('cursorCost', cursorCost);
}

function load() {
cookies = localStorage.getItem('cookies');
cookies = parseInt(cookies);
cursors = localStorage.getItem('cursors');
cursors = parseInt(cursors);
cursorCost = localStorage.getItem('cursorCost');
cursorCost = parseInt(cursorCost); 
update();
}
```

Comment: The function `save` can't access `cursorCost` because it's a `var` inside another function - `buyCursor`. And `load` assigns a global `var` also named `cursorCost`. It's wrong.

Comment: @Benny how would you recommend I adjust this? As it also doesn't work for "cursors" alone, but works perfectly for "cookies"

Comment: You're not showing all your code, so I can't say. For example, I cant see `update` function, and I cant see where `buyCursor` is called. Your code that saves and loads individual local storage values is correct,  but without full code I can't identify the problem.

Comment: @Benny that is the full .js file, the rest is on the index which is just <button onClick="buyCursor()"> and  <span I'd="cursors">  with the script link

Comment: I suggest doing one or more of the following: • trim as much code as possible while leaving the failed code, in order to stay with the most simple example that demonstrates the problem • upload your full code to playground like jsbin,  stackblitz,  codepen,  etc. and share it here • check you dev tools console for error messages

Comment: @Benny Hello, here is the code https://jsbin.com/cikiyewipa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Benny it seems to save but not load

Comment: When you say `cursors` in javascript, it refers to the element with the same id, in your case it's `<span id="cursors">`, not a numeric value. You may intend to refer to the element's content, like this: `cursors.innerText`?

Comment: Hello @Benny I managed to fix, it basically was because I didn't create the update function and I have to use ``` cursors.innerHTML ``` instead... I also realised my var for cursorCost was inside the function as you said so I adjusted that, and I then had an issue where it saved and loaded everything but new cursor cost... Fortunately I did a bit of trial and error and put the math.floor and so on into the update function for the cursorCost... And vwala it now works perfectly! Thank you for all your help, I know it was a tricky one... I'm quite new at JavaScript myself!

Comment: Glad it works and that I helped.